# Any risk of breaking anaconda python when force upgrading packages using conda-forge?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, pypi, conda-forge

In my anaconda setup, some python packages like arrow in anaconda uses the pypi channel. However, these packages are not the latest version. The latest version is found in the conda-forge channel. For example, to upgrade to the latest version of arrow using conda-forge, I run the following command;

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge arrow
```

There should be some reason why the default channel is pypi and not conda-forge. So, will there be any risk of breaking anaconda packages if I were to force upgrade packages using conda-forge channel?

I installed anaconda 2018.12 which runs on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

The safest thing to do is to make a new env

```
conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge arrow
```

The most dangerous thing to do, in my anecdotal experience of seeing people on StackOverflow with broken Conda installations, is to install things in **base**. Unfortunately, this is what many Anaconda users do, likely because Anaconda distributes with everything installed in **base** already.